# creatNewFile method in java does not create file while no exception is thrown

Tags: java, file

I am trying to create a new file and write in it. The path that I have specified has been manually created, no problem there. But it does not throw any exception, yet the file is not being created:-

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    public class WriteFile {

String filename="";
String path="D:\\myfiles";
public String write(String content, String name) throws IOException{
    filename=name+".txt";
    File file=new File(path+filename);
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    String[] lines=content.split("\n");
    PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(path+filename,"utf-8");
    for(String line:lines){
        writer.println(line);
    }
    writer.close();
    return filename;
}

}
```

Comment: Set your path like that. `String path="D:\\myfiles\\";`. hope this works.

Comment: Oops, my bad :D, Thanks

Comment: In 'D:\' it should be a file that starts with 'myfiles' and have extension '.txt'.

Comment: If you think a file is not being created, it usually means it is not being create where you think it is.

Comment: @SohamBanerjee I add the answer and if works then plz accept.

Comment: It is specified to return a Boolean, not throw an exception, but you should get rid of the `exists()/createNewFile()` code altogether. It just anticipates and repeats work that `new PrintWriter()` has to do anyway. There is no benefit. As to the file, if it isn't being created, `new PrintWriter()` will certainly throw an exception. The conclusion therefore us that it is being created, just not where you expect, as @PeterLawrey stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your path like that. I think you want to create a text file under this `D:\\myfiles\\` location. So set your path like that,

```
String path="D:\\myfiles\\";
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes, if you expect a file separator in a particular place you should ensure one is there, rather than rely on the input being correct.

Other notes:

- pass values via arguments on the method where possible (unless this is getting too complicated)
- `new File(parent, file)` will put in a separator as required, and handle when you put one in already.
- don't use a field when you can use a local variable.
- you don't need to create a file before you write to it.
- you don't need to split a file into lines, so you can write it out as lines.
- you can use try-with-resource to ensure a resource is always closed.
- if you can make a method or class `static` then do so as it make it clear you don't depend on any instance.

In short

```
public static String write(String content, String path, String filename) throws IOException {
    File file=new File(path, filename);
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8")) {
        writer.println(content);
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```